# creation of a folder in a specific /home folder from a derived docker image doesn't work

Tags: docker, directory, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

In a `Dockerfile`, I have existing folders from my derived image `/home` and `/root`. I cannot create a folder in the `/home` directory:

> RUN mkdir -p /home/TEST_3

No error messages are display but I can see that the folder was not created.
The same command is working fine in the `/root` directory

Bother folder seems to be similar in term of permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 home
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:38 root
```

The hard link count is different. The problematic folder `/home`has more permission

Another strange thing is that I can create a folder in `/home` using:

> WORKDIR /home/TEST_2

but then any file that I create in this folder doesn't seems to exist.

Here a small `Dockerfile` to recreate this issue/feature

```
# Specify the base image and tag
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-cpu:m27

RUN ls -la
RUN ls -la /home/
RUN ls -la /root/

## creation ofthe folder is working and the folder exist (and I can create a file in the new folder)
RUN mkdir -p /root/TEST_1
RUN ls -la /root/TEST_1
RUN touch /root/TEST_1/new_file.txt
RUN ls -la /root/TEST_1

## creation of the folder is working and the folder exist but the file created doesn't exist
WORKDIR /home/TEST_2
WORKDIR /
RUN ls -la /home/TEST_2
RUN touch /home/TEST_2/new_file.txt
RUN ls -la /home/TEST_2

## creation of the folder succeed (no error messages), but the folder doesn't exist
RUN mkdir -p /home/TEST_3
RUN ls -la /home/TEST_3
RUN touch /home/TEST_3/new_file.txt
RUN ls -la /home/TEST_3
```

and here the output:

```
 docker build -f Dockerfile_test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  37.89kB
Step 1/17 : FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-cpu:m27
 ---> 7eb6565a8cc6
Step 2/17 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Running in 1ced0ed2bf49
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Oct 26 12:52 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:20 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Oct 26 12:52 dev
-rwxr-x--x   1 root root   94 Jun 19 21:51 entrypoint.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jun 20 08:38 env.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:22 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 16:55 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 16:54 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 16:54 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:23 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 226 root root    0 Oct 26 12:52 proc
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:38 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:33 run
-rwxr-x--x   1 root root  109 Jun 19 21:51 run_jupyter.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:20 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 16:54 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Oct 26 12:52 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 10:09 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:33 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 12 16:55 var
Removing intermediate container 1ced0ed2bf49
 ---> 87dbdffa7315
Step 3/17 : RUN ls -la /home/
 ---> Running in 756f013caf7f
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 ..
Removing intermediate container 756f013caf7f
 ---> 24419a25ac99
Step 4/17 : RUN ls -la /root/
 ---> Running in bde249ae0452
total 52
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3106 Apr  9  2018 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:31 .cache
drwxrwsr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:26 .conda
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:33 .config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  401 Jun 20 08:33 .gitconfig
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:38 .ipython
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 20 10:10 .jupyter
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 20 08:31 .npm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  405 Jun 20 10:10 .wget-hsts
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jun 20 10:09 miniconda3
Removing intermediate container bde249ae0452
 ---> f6e6b3780145
Step 5/17 : RUN mkdir -p /root/TEST_1
 ---> Running in 95ffe0bc574f
Removing intermediate container 95ffe0bc574f
 ---> a87cac09ec17
Step 6/17 : RUN ls -la /root/TEST_1
 ---> Running in b8fd10afa3ee
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 .
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 ..
Removing intermediate container b8fd10afa3ee
 ---> 87b173385d4b
Step 7/17 : RUN touch /root/TEST_1/new_file.txt
 ---> Running in cbdd9ac79955
Removing intermediate container cbdd9ac79955
 ---> 0f57f2c15855
Step 8/17 : RUN ls -la /root/TEST_1
 ---> Running in 0a7d46a44e9e
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:53 .
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 12:53 new_file.txt
Removing intermediate container 0a7d46a44e9e
 ---> 5413892c3b96
Step 9/17 : WORKDIR /home/TEST_2
 ---> Running in d0322094ae3b
Removing intermediate container d0322094ae3b
 ---> 9815f6870830
Step 10/17 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Running in f84feebf3db9
Removing intermediate container f84feebf3db9
 ---> 5c85f2fadd04
Step 11/17 : RUN ls -la /home/TEST_2
 ---> Running in 4644cbcd5c3c
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:53 ..
Removing intermediate container 4644cbcd5c3c
 ---> c82625e638d9
Step 12/17 : RUN touch /home/TEST_2/new_file.txt
 ---> Running in ac89ce336a51
Removing intermediate container ac89ce336a51
 ---> d9569d5ca42d
Step 13/17 : RUN ls -la /home/TEST_2
 ---> Running in 999f75b4ece1
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 26 12:53 ..
Removing intermediate container 999f75b4ece1
 ---> 57062c0ccf0a
Step 14/17 : RUN mkdir -p /home/TEST_3
 ---> Running in f9788ac58dc7
Removing intermediate container f9788ac58dc7
 ---> e88a503ae524
Step 15/17 : RUN ls -la /home/TEST_3
 ---> Running in 16ea32c637c6
ls: cannot access '/home/TEST_3': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls -la /home/TEST_3' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I am using `Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5` on `MacOS 10.14.6`

My questions are the following:

1. where is comming the difference (be able to create a folder in`/root` but not in `/home`
2. how to fix this issue to be able to create a folder in `/home` and
   be able to create files as well in the new folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

> what is the difference between /home and /root

/home has a volume associated with it

> how to get around the issue

create the file on entry-point (after the container is built), OR create the file inside the volume (I use the first option in my long answer)

### Long answer:

Running a `docker inspect containerId` after building the Image & container show theirs a volumes assocated with the home directory:

```
"Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1447dbc568742221a757a650427f38fb485e42fc7c6e959f33966922fe862d13/_data",
                "Destination": "/home",
```

The volume is RW (read write), so you can write to the file once inside the container. (I tested using `docker exec -it containerId /bin/sh` then `touch /home/TEST_2/new_file.txt`)

Try using an Entrypoint script to create the folders/files.

### Edit:

I wanted to see for myself, but ran into a couple hurdles. The parent container (gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-cpu:m27) already has an `entrypoint.sh` file.

Also, adding a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command will override the parents entrypoint container (which you probably want).

**Working Solution**:

From the host, COPY the entrypoint.sh file (Assuming you want to modify it on your host). `docker cp containerId:/entrypoint.sh .`

Modify the entrypoint, adding your TOUCH commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/TEST_2/new_file.txt # <-- I added this
. /env.sh
. /root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
exec "$@"
```

Change your dockerfile to copy the new `entrypoint.sh`, which will replace the existing one:

`COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh`

Your listing commands on startup will be the same, however if you go into the container you will see your file:

```
# ls home/TEST_2
new_file.txt
#
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was missing. Do I get it right when I say that everything time I run the container, the file new_file.txt will be recreate on the /home volume since the entrypoint.sh script we be call  ?

Comment: @Dr.FabienTarrade Yep I believe so